# Cropped/Rotates view background on ios8

Tags: layout, screen-orientation, ios8

If you create an app (single view app for example), and you set on your project Portrait and Landscape Right (in this order), then on your view controller you overwrite the method `supportedInterfaceOrientations` with `return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;` when you start this app on any ios version except 8 you can see your view perfectly but if you install it on iOS8 you can see that the background it rotated (or cropped).

I read something about that now it's interface oriented but I still can't find the solution.

[image: This sample on ios 8 simulator]